# O365 REST API Calendar: Multiple Conditions with Clientlibrary

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm using the O365 Clientlibrary to get some Events from the user calendar.
I only want events between a defined timespan (4 days).
Unfortunately I get a error message when I define more condidtions.

Code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var events = await client.Me.Events.Where(x => date.AddDays(-1) > x.Start && x.End < date.AddDays(3)).ExecuteAsync();
```

ErrorMessage:

> {"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter","message":"The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."}}

It works when I use only one condition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the query as follows:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var events = await client.Me.Events.Where(x => x.Start < date.AddDays(-1) && x.End < date.AddDays(3)).ExecuteAsync();
```

Let me know if  this works with you.